# Calculate missing number

Tags: ruby

Here's the exercise:

> You have been given a list of sequential numbers from 1 to 10,000, but
>   they are all out of order; furthermore, a single number is missing
>   from the list. The object of the task is to find out which number is
>   missing.

[The strategy](http://www.dev102.com/2008/06/30/a-programming-job-interview-challenge-10-the-missing-number/) to this problem is to sum the elements in the array, then sum the range 1 to 10,000, and subtract the difference. This is equal to the missing number. The formula for calculating the sum of the range from `1..n` being `n(n+1)/2`.

This is my current approach:

```
def missing_number(array)
  sum = 0
  array.each do |element|
  sum += element
  end

  ((10000*10001)/2) - sum
end
```

Where I am getting tripped up is the output when I input an array such as this:

```
puts missing_number(*1..10000) #=> 0
```

Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, passing `*1..10000` shouldn’t be working… that’s going to expand into 10,000 arguments. Passing `1..10000`, on the other hand, *should* result in zero! None of the numbers are missing.

Answer (score 4):

No need to sort the array.  An array of length N is supposed to have all but one of the numbers `1..(N+1)` so the array length + 1 is the basis for figuring out what the grand_sum would be if all values were there.

```
def missing_number(array)
  grand_sum = (array.length + 1) * (array.length + 2) / 2
  grand_sum - array.inject(:+)
end
```

**ADDENDUM**

This method takes an array as an argument, not a range.  You can't use a range directly because there wouldn't be a missing value.  Before calling the method you need some mechanism for generating an array which meets the problem description.  Here's one possible solution:

```
PROBLEM_SIZE = 10_000
# Create an array corresponding to the range
test_array = (1..PROBLEM_SIZE).to_a
# Target a random value for deletion -- rand(N) generates values in
# the range 0..N-1, inclusive, so add 1 to shift the range to 1..N
target_value = rand(PROBLEM_SIZE) + 1
# Delete the value and print so we can check the algorithm
printf "Deleting %d from the array\n", test_array.delete(target_value)
# Randomize the order of remaining values, as per original problem description
test_array.shuffle!
# See what the missing_number() method identifies as the missing number                     
printf "Algorithm identified %d as the deleted value\n", \
       missing_number(test_array)
```

Comment: Good optimization, I missed that in mine.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: it's more than an optimization, you won't get the correct answer by finding the largest of the remaining values if the one that was deleted was the max.

Comment: @pjs, I'm hoping to understand how to solve this without using #inject.  I'd like to use solve it using #each if possible.

Comment: @NicholasJayanty: Not sure why you want to avoid `inject`, it's a very powerful tool.  However, if you calculate `grand_sum` as above then `sum = 0; array.each {|n| sum += n}; grand_sum - sum` should do the trick.

Comment: @pjs thank you!  I'm excited to learn #inject as I've seen it across all the boards, but I'm trying to master #each before I graduate to 'more power' :) Thank you so much for your generosity.

Comment: @pjs, one more question.  What would your input statement look like when you go to test? I'm thinking puts missing_number([1..10000])?

Comment: @NicholasJayanty: I tested using `irb`: `x = (1..100).to_a; x.delete 42; missing_number(x)`.  I didn't actually put semicolons, those were three separate lines.  I strongly recommend playing around in `irb` to learn.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to solving the problem if it's not performance critical, because of its readability:

```
def missing_number(array)
  (1..10_000).to_a - array
end
```

Comment: This violates the O(1) additional memory constraint in the original problem description linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `*1..10000`, the argument should be `(1..10000).to_a`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `*1..10000`, this will just expand to 10,000 arguments. `(1..10000).to_a` will return zero because there are no elements missing between `1..10000` you need to *remove* one. Below is some code with a detailed explanation.

```
def missing_number array
  # put elements in order                                                                
  array.sort!

  # get value of last array element                                                      
  last  = array[-1]

  # compute the expected total of the numbers                                            
  # 1 - last 
  # (n + 1)(n)/2                                                               
  expected = (last + 1) * (last / 2)

  # actual sum                                                                           
  actual = array.inject{|sum,x| sum + x}

  # find missing number by subtracting                                                   
  (expected - actual)
end

test = (1..10000).to_a
test.delete 45
puts "Missing number is: #{missing_number(test)}"
```

Comment: ! Thanks for the detailed explanation. If you weren't going to use inject what would be the approach?  I haven't quite grasped inject yet, and was hoping to use an iterator like #each.

Comment: # get value of last array element                                                      
  last  = array[-1] => wouldn't this index a value outside of the range, wouldn't last element be indexed as array[9999] if the range was 10000?

Comment: array indexing starts at 0, 10,000 values occupy indices from 0 - 9,999

Comment: @NicholasJayanty: In Ruby negative array indices indicate you're looking from the end of the array, so array[-1] is the last element, array[-2] is the second from last, etc.

Comment: Yes, in this case `array[-1]` and `array[9999]` are the same.